# NextJS App Router: How to display error in production

Tags: next.js, error-handling, production, app-router

I have a server action which I'm calling in a client component when submitting a form. Here is the code:

```
export async function editIdeation({
  body
}: EditIdeationProps): Promise<EditIdeationResponse> {
  const token = getCookie();

  try {
    const data = await PATCH<EditIdeationBody, EditIdeationResponse>(
      url,
      token,
      "default",
      body
    );

    revalidatePath(url);

    return data;
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      throw new Error(error.message);
    } else {
      throw new Error("An unknown error occurred");
    }
  }
}
```

In development, I get the error message properly, however in production I get this message instead: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.

How can I get the actual error message from the api in production?

Comment: In your server logs, aren't getting the detailed error messages?

Comment: I need to display the error in the UI

Comment: It's not a very common thing to display full error messages to the client in production (security concerns). I think that's why Next.js is disabling them.

Comment: I might have not been clear. I didn't mean I want to display the entire message directly from the stack trace or something like that. Ideally I'd like to display a generic message based on the status code or something like that. However, anything thrown in an Error object seems to just be swallowed and gives that weird error message. I don't think it's a very good user experience at all.